# How get list of physical and logical disks?

Tags: c++, winapi

How i can get list of physical disks with list logical disks for each of physical disk with WinApi and C++. Main goal determine link between physical and logical disks. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have time for full answer, but `FindFirstVolume` for volumes, `SetupDiGetClassDevs` for physical disks and remember, that a volume may span multiple disks.

Comment: I guess that what avakar means is this is probably the kind of information that's documented. Did you have a look at the doc, if yes, is there something you don't understand inside ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier solution than avakar's idea: [`QueryDosDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365461(v=vs.85).aspx). You'll need to pass drive letters, which you can get from [`GetLogicalDriveStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975(v=vs.85).aspx), and you get the physical name back.

Comment: Beware that logical drives and volumes are not equivalent. Multiple drives can refer to the same volume, or no volume at all (if the drive points to a network location).

Comment: @avakar: Yup, the relation between the two can be quite complicated (I'm also ignoring tiered storage, for instance). Any easy solution will miss the unusual cases.

Comment: Not all volumes or drives have drive letters, and some can be mount points in other volumes.

Comment: That's a total nonsense. `QueryDosDevice` returns string in `\Device\HarddiskVolume#` format. That's a list of internal names for volumes, not the physical drive names. Those look like `\Device\PhysicalDrive#`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code for the world that may be useful.  It doesn't really introduce anything new, because it uses API [`QueryDosDeviceX()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-querydosdevicea) kindly called out by @MSalters.  But this code might close the gap for someone who simply needs an output like this, without having to sample all APIs mentioned in this thread, or coding the different possible inputs, etc.   This also happens to be my favorite and arguably most useful of the methods mentioned.

This code is compiled and tested by me.  The featured `Output` is an actual screen-scrape from the console window this code ran in just minutes ago.  Enjoy...

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_DRIVES  24

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    get_all_drives_qdd()

    Uses API:
    DWORD QueryDosDeviceA(
      [in, optional] LPCSTR lpDeviceName,
      [out]          LPSTR  lpTargetPath,
      [in]           DWORD  ucchMax
    );
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int get_all_drives_qdd(char mssg[MAX_DRIVES][100])
{
    int yyy, offs;
    char  lpTargetPath[100] = {0};
    DWORD res;

    for(yyy=offs=0; yyy < MAX_DRIVES ; yyy++)
    {
        char szBuff[10];
        sprintf(szBuff, "%c:", 'A' + yyy + 2 );
        res = QueryDosDevice(szBuff, lpTargetPath, sizeof(lpTargetPath) );
        if(res && lpTargetPath[0])
        {
            sprintf(mssg[offs++], "%s %s", szBuff, lpTargetPath);
        }
    }
    return offs;
}


int main() 
{
    char mssgs[MAX_DRIVES][100] = {0};
    int iii, drives = get_all_drives_qdd(mssgs);

    printf("Captured %d valid drives:\n", drives);
    
    for(iii = 0; iii < drives; iii++)
        printf("\t%s\n", mssgs[iii]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    Captured 7 valid drives:
        C: \Device\HarddiskVolume2
        D: \Device\HarddiskVolume3
        E: \Device\HarddiskVolume5
        F: \Device\HarddiskVolume4
        G: \Device\CdRom0
        J: \Device\HarddiskVolume8
        R: \Device\ImDisk0
```